# c system() syntax error due to corruption in the environment

Tags: c, unix, ksh

Very strange behavior in my C code on AIX 6.1 (KSH Version M-11/16/88f):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){    
int status;
//...
// parse arguments
// do things
//...
status=system("echo hello");
}
```

Sometimes the `system` call fails (even though args are not taken into account in building the system command, i.e "echo hello" ).

When it fails I get this message:

```
[[[: 0403-057 Syntax error
```

By tracing the executable with:

```
truss -aef -o truss.log my_exec args...
```

(note option `-e` for viewing the environment strings which are passed in each exec system call)

I noticed that at some point the environment is modified with the addition of a "corrupt" variable `RDV_CALCULATE_M[[[[`.
**That is the cause of the syntax error**. In fact if a directly issue this command in the shell:

```
export RDV_CALCULATE_M[[[[
```

I get the same error:

```
[[[: 0403-057 Syntax error
```

So, by now I'm sure it's not my code that directly changes the environment, but possibly something in the libraries I use.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){    
int status;
/*...
parse arguments
do things with external library
external library messes with the environment
*/
status=system("echo hello"); --> fails because environment is corrupted
}
```

Comment: can you provide examples which work and which doesn't work?

Comment: This syntax error comes from the shell and has nothing to do with this C code, given that this is the _only_ call to `system` in your program.

Comment: Where do you declare `status`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry, code is a bit complex and I cannot share it to the public. I'm sure it could better help for an answer, but here also suggestions and hypotesis are welcome: what factors can affect a pretty simple `system` call (even when it contains a const string)

Comment: @P.P. The system call fails even when i pass directly a constant string like "echo Hello"

Comment: @MDXF in main (edited the question)

Comment: The code you're showing us would not produce that error. In fact the code in the question is invalid for C99 and later, since you don't have the required `#include <stdlib.h>` You need to show us code that actually does produce the error, even if it's not exactly the same as the code you're using. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: `echo` may not be the best choice because may be built-in (although it should work through `system`). Can you try `ls` instead?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: That shouldn't matter. The behavior of `echo hello` is well defined whether `echo` is a built-in or not.

Comment: @KeithThompson let's not forget that we're in a CIA-like kind of code, so we only have to guess...

Comment: The reported error message is `[[[: 0403-057 Syntax error`. I don't  recall seeing anything like that `0403-057` in a shell error message. **CORRECTION**: Apparently (some versions of) ksh produce messages like that, and `/bin/sh`, which is what `system()` invokes, might be ksh. A Google search for the error message might be helpful.

Comment: A question for the OP: How do you know that *that* particular call to `system()` is the one causing the error message?

Comment: To confirm.   lets call this program `foo`.  Your question implies `./foo SomeArgList1` works, and `./foo SomeArgList2` gives the syntax error.  What are the actual arguments in cases of`SomeArgList1` and `SomeArgList2`

Comment: @infixed: I suggest that knowing what arguments cause the problem is useless unless we can see the actual code that has the problem. The question is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: If the problem is related to the parameters, try using environment-variables to pass the to the shell-command. Here is an example: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/ekezet.html#Q0121

Comment: I think I found the leading cause for the error. I also figured out a workaround "answer" that I would share, but I see no "Answer your own question" button. Is it because question is [closed]?

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests some `ksh` or `bash` code is being fed to the Bourne shell.

Make sure you double check the man page for `system(3)`.  AIX is (used to be) based on System V, so it almost certainly calls `/bin/sh`.  Even if it's a link to the Korn shell, it may behave differently when called as `/bin/sh`.

Solaris, also System V based, has a `truss` (http://opensolarisforum.org/man/man1/truss.html) utility.  I've heard that AIX has something similar;  it may help you find out what shell is being called, and if any shell functions are coming into play.

I wish I could help more, but I can't find the AIX man pages online, and the last time I used AIX was version 3 or 4.

Comment: `truss` is also available for AIX. I'm going to use it and let you know

Comment: Thx @Erik Bennett! `truss` helped me finding the cause. See my edits above.